# How do you expose gatling assertions in the gatling reports?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I have a gatling test suite and in the simulation script I have a few assertions testing that the average mean response time of groups/requests meets a certain threshold. I am using gradle to drive the suite and some assertions fail as expected.

However, when I look at the gatling test reports I see no indication of failed assertions. How do I expose the fact that certain assertions have failed based on looking at the report alone?

The gatling suite is integrated in the CI which spits out the gatling report as an artefact. We want visibility in the team as to which assertions failed by looking at the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible at the moment. Could you open a feature request on github, please?

Comment: I just saw the issue list and looks like there already is. https://github.com/excilys/gatling/issues/1057 Thank you! This answers my question!